# How to toggle css class of a single element in a .map() function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have a .map() function where I'm iterating over an array and rendering elements, like so:

```
      {options.map((option, i) => (
        <TachyonsSimpleSelectOption
          options={options[i]}
          key={i}
          onClick={() => this.isSelected(i)}
          selected={this.toggleStyles("item")}
        />
```

I am toggling the state of a selected element like so:

```
isSelected (i) {
    this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected }, () => { console.log(this.state.selected) })
}
```

Using a switch statement to change the styles:

```
  toggleStyles(el) {
    switch (el) {
      case "item":
        return this.state.selected ? "bg-light-gray" : "";
        break;
    }
  }
```

And then passing it in my `toggleStyles` method as props to the className of the `TachyonsSimpleSelectOption` Component.

### Problem

The class is being toggled for all items in the array, but I only want to target the currently clicked item.

[Link to Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwk71420op)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the `selected` state incorrectly.

In your code, to determine whether it is selected or not, you depends on that state, but you didn't specify which items that is currently selected.

Instead saving a boolean state, you can store which index is currently selected so that only specified item is affected.

This may be a rough answer, but I hope I can give you some ideas.

on your render:

```
{options.map((option, i) => (
  <TachyonsSimpleSelectOption
    options={options[i]}
    key={i}
    onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedItem: i })}
    selected={this.determineItemStyle(i)}
   />
))}
```

on the function that will determine the `selected` props value:

```
determineItemStyle(i) {
  const isItemSelected = this.state.selectedItem === i;
  return isItemSelected ? "bg-light-gray" : "";
}
```

Hope this answer will give you some eureka moment

Comment: makes total sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling react which element is toggled. Since the state has just a boolean value `selected`, it doesn't know which element is selected.

In order to do that, change your `isSelected` function to :

```
isSelected (i) {
  this.setState({ selected: i }, () => { 
    console.log(this.state.selected) })
}
```

Now, the React state knows that the item on index `i` is selected. Use that to toggle your class now.

In case you want to store multiple selected items, you need to store an array of indices instead of just one index

Answer (score 0):

TachyonsSimpleSelectOption.js:

```
import React from 'react';

class Option extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { selected, name } = this.props;
    return(
       <h1 
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        style={{backgroundColor: selected ? 'grey' : 'white'}}
       >Hello {name}!</h1>
    )
  }
}
export default Option;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import TachyonsSimpleSelectOption from "./TachyonsSimpleSelectOption";

const options = ["apple", "pear", "orange"];

const styles = {
  selected: "bg-light-gray"
};

class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      selected: []
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
    this.isSelected = this.isSelected.bind(this);
  }

  handleBlur() {
    this.toggleMenu(close);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.toggleMenu();
  }

  toggleMenu(close) {
    this.setState(
      {
        open: !this.state.open
      },
      () => {
        this.toggleStyles("menu");
      }
    );
  }

  toggleStyles(el, index) {
    switch (el) {
      case "menu":
        return this.state.open ? "db" : "dn";
        break;
      case "item":
        const { selected } = this.state;
        return selected.indexOf(index) !== -1;
        break;
    }
  }

  isSelected(i) {
    let { selected } = this.state;
    if (selected.indexOf(i) === -1) {
      selected.push(i);
    } else {
      selected = selected.filter(index => index !== i);
    }
    this.setState({ selected});
  }

  render() {
    const { options } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className="flex flex-column ba"
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        tabIndex={0}
      >
        <div className="flex-row pa3" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <span className="flex-grow-1 w-50 dib">Title</span>
          <span className="flex-grow-1 w-50 dib tr">^</span>
        </div>
        <div className={this.toggleStyles("menu")}>
          {options.map((option, i) => (
            <TachyonsSimpleSelectOption
              name={options[i]}
              key={i}
              onClick={() => this.isSelected(i)}
              selected={this.toggleStyles("item", i)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Select options={options} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And [Link to Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/40555m5zj7)